# RTK Query query parameter

Tags: reactjs, redux, rtk-query

I want to send request like this
https://pixabay.com/api/?key=1231231231231&per_page=10.
But this code sends request like this
https://pixabay.com/api/?key=1231231231231/per_page=10.
How do I fix it? Can't get how to set query parameter

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const api = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: `https://pixabay.com/api/?key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`,
  }),
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getPhotos: builder.query({
      query: (limit = 10) => `per_page=${limit}`,
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetPhotosQuery } = api;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
query: (limit = 10) => `per_page=${limit}`,
```

is just short for

```js
query: (limit = 10) => ({
  url: `per_page=${limit}`,
  method: 'GET'
}),
```

you probably want to do something like

```js
query: (limit = 10) => ({
  params: { per_page: limit }
}),
```

Comment: Where did the `url` prop in `query: (limit = 10) => ({params: { per_page: limit }}),` go?

Comment: in this case, it would be an empty string so no need to specify it.

Answer (score 0):

```
getPhotos: builder.query({
  query: (limit = 10) => ({
    url: "",
    method: "GET",
    params: { per_page: limit },
  }),
}),
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 